# PHP Fix Warning: ini_set(): A session is active

Tags: php

I have this Config File:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1); //This line 4 and error Line
```

and this config loader:

```
namespace App\Core;
class Config
{
    // this is public to allow better Unit Testing
    public static $config;

    public static function get($key)
    {
        if (!self::$config) {

            $config_file = '../application/config/config.' . Environment::get() . '.php';

            if (!file_exists($config_file)) {
                return false;
            }

            self::$config = require $config_file;
        }

        return self::$config[$key];
    }
}
```

And this `controller.php`:

```
namespace App\Core;

/**
 * This is the "base controller class". All other "real" controllers extend this class.
 * Whenever a controller is created, we also
 * 1. initialize a session
 */
class Controller
{
    public $templates;
    public function __construct()
    {
        // always initialize a session
        Session::init();

        Auth::checkSessionConcurrency();

        $this->templates = new \League\Plates\Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));
        $this->db = new DB(Config::get('DB_TYPE'), Config::get('DB_HOST'), Config::get('DB_USER'), Config::get('DB_PASS'), Config::get('DB_NAME'), Config::get('DB_PORT'));
    }
}
```

Now for index controller I have:

```
namespace App\Front\Controller;
use App\Front\Model\NoteModel;
use App\Core\Config;
class IndexController extends \App\Core\Controller
{
    /**
     * Construct this object by extending the basic Controller class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        echo $this->templates->render('index/index', [NoteModel::getAllNotes()]);

    }
}
```

Now in action(PHP 7.2) I see This Error:

> Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\config\config.development.php on line 4

**I know**: cant put `ini_set` after session start in php > 7:

[https://3v4l.org/hp0sg](http://Check%20PHP%20Code%20Online)

**MY FIX:**
I work with controller and **Move** this two line to before `Session::init();` in Controller.php:

```
$this->templates = new \League\Plates\Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));
$this->db = new DB(Config::get('DB_TYPE'), Config::get('DB_HOST'), Config::get('DB_USER'), Config::get('DB_PASS'), Config::get('DB_NAME'), Config::get('DB_PORT'));
```

And In action Not see/show error. What's Problem and My FIX(Move code to before session) is true way?!
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not just set those ini settings in php.ini?

Comment: @delboy1978uk: your mean is create/add a `php.ini` in my script root folder and remove from config file?!

Comment: Your php installation will have a php.ini in your xampp folder somehwre. Find it, change the settings to match your code, and restart apache. If it works I'll write a proper answer so other people will know what to do.(it should work)

Comment: @delboy1978uk: Sure but if I cant access to edit `php.ini` in server I cant fix this warning.

Comment: are you running PHP as an apache module? if so you can change settings in `.htaccess` too. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: Failing all that, I would put those settings on your index.php right at the start

Comment: @delboy1978uk: if add in index.php is fix and not show warning message but how do check this ini_set enable and work true?!

Comment: user ini_get(); may be in your controller to check the configuration value 

echo ini_get('session.cookie_httponly'); die('---stop here---');